# Wordpress OAuth I can not get the access token

Tags: wordpress, oauth

What I do:

1 I'm going for the authorization

https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=256&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2faltinorge.com%3a333%2findex.fast%3faction%3dwordpress

And get a callback and code

2 Now I have to get the access token

https://public-api.wordpress.com/oauth2/token?client_id=256&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2faltinorge.com%3a333%2findex.fast%3faction%3dwordpress&client_secret=KH78PsklKI4uACufFdkSA3DyuknaYshQPxmAbROhRFXvLN71B6S4xhS9y3IMq4St&code=Cber6PVJVe&grant_type=authorization_code

But getting (405) Method Not Allowed

---

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922794/sign-in-with-wordpress

Comment: If you using OAuth2 you had to implement HTTPS.